# Entra Inbound Provisioning API not setting accountexpiry for on-premise AD

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I am using Entra Inbound Provisioning API to add new user on-premise. I can successfully add a user, but I'm unable to set the `accountexpire` attribute.

Below is the link that I have followed to configure Provisioning API:

[CLICK HERE](https://goodworkaround.com/2023/08/01/testing-out-the-entra-id-inbound-provisioning-api/)

When I checked the documentation attribute in Local AD it shows that its of type long integer. However in Provisioning API mapping we are not able to specify "long integer". I was only able to specify it as string or integer and I tried both. Below is the C# code I tried to convert the date to a long integer but it did not work:

```
string endDate = "2023-12-31"
var expiryDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate).ToFileTime();
```

Please suggest a way to do this.